# differnt behaviour between clang and microsoft c++/QT5 with constructors and return values

Tags: visual-studio, qt, c++11, clang

According to microsoft visual studio 2013 (being built from QT creator, QT 5.4), this code is fine:

```
#include <string>
struct X {
  X(std::string const &) {};
};

X wibble() { return ""; }
```

clang however says

```
test.cpp(53) : error: no viable conversion from 'const char [1]' to 'X'
X wibble() { return ""; }

test.cpp(49) : note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [1]' to 'const X &' for 1st argument
struct X {

test.cpp(49) : note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [1]' to 'X &&' for 1st argument
struct X {

test.cpp(50) : note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [1]' to 'const std::string &' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > &') for 1st argument
X(std::string const &) {};
```

It does the same thing with QString for what it's worth. Assuming clang is correct, why is it complaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't compile even in `MinGW`, because it is illegal. Because only one level of user-defined implicit conversion is legal. In your code you have 2 level conversion: to `std::string` and to `X`.

```
struct X {
  X( std::string const &) {}
};

X wibble1() { return ""; }    // 2 level: error
X wibble2() { return X(""); } // 1 level: ok
```

Even here you have same error:

```
void foobar(X x) {
}

int main()
{
    foobar(X(""));// ok, 1 level
    foobar ("f"); 
    // error: could not convert '(const char*)"f"' from 'const char*' to 'X'
}
```